# How to add trail path for moving sprite in andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm working on a game copter (http://i1-games.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/Copter_1.jpg). When you touch the screen, you go upwards otherwise you'll go downwards. So you are changing the position of the sprite.

Now I want a trailpath for my sprite, does anybody who has an idea how to do it? Here is an example of how it should look like:

[image: trailpath]

Tips for on the center line are good enough. If you have an idea how to do the gradient, let me know!

Comment: @Racoon Yes, you can call is a tail!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Particles. You can look [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/) or better [HERE](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/tree/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples) this 3 examples:

- ParticleSystemSimpleExample
- ParticleSystemCoolExample
- ParticleSystemNexusExample

Comment: Thanks fry your answer, byt why are particles the best solution for remembering the last coordinates of the sprite? Or is this answer for the gradient (I saw the ColorParticleModifier)?

Comment: Sorry, yes, this was answer to gradient. Hmm, I didn't see the ColorParticleModifier.. I will have a look. Your first question was about solid line(tail)?

Comment: Yes about a tail. Now can i use a tail with the particle system. Only things now is how to make a nice tail.

Comment: but if you use the same particles, but smaller and don't change opacity.

Comment: maybe you can send me to email that part with particles or post here? Thanks

Comment: the problem now is that i dont get a smooth line, its only dotted by the frequence from the input, changing the number wont work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RemyStrijker Old but there is a simple way to achieve a smooth line like in the picture: 1. store the moving path (points) 2. calculate the vertices to both sides of each point orthogonally to the path 3. create a polygon using  those points (using TexturedPolygon class for instance).

Comment: @RemyStrijker could you please post the answer which worked for you to create the tail image above..?