# Particles Tail on a moving Sprite with AndEngine

Tags: andengine, particles

I'm trying to create a tail for a sprite that is moving on the screen.

I need something like this:
[How to add trail path for moving sprite in andengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841369/how-to-add-trail-path-for-moving-sprite-in-andengine/13841481#13841481?newreg=16d6a154bcb74d4b86e88e43fc142c53)

Unfortunally, the one asking the question didn't explain how he succeded in creating the tail (even if "dotted").What I'm able to do is create a tail that resided in the emitting sprite, but when I rotate the sprite, also the tail rotates creating an artificial effect that is not nice at all.

So I'd like to have a tail that once is "emitted" remains still respecting the sccene.

Comment: You probably attached particle emitter to your srite, and when you move your sprite or rotate it all particles move and rotate with it? Do I understand it corectly? if yes, I had simillar problem and if I recall it I created additional object that was copying a position of a sprite and this object had a emitter attached. Later today I will try to find my code and post it here, but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Yes, you got the situation... I'll wait to see the code to fully grasp your method. I too tried to create a new object (Rectangle) that onManagedUpdate was positioning itself near the main object and that had the emitter on it, but didin't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
PointParticleEmitter emitter = new PointParticleEmitter(240, 400){

        public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed){
            super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

            setCenterX(star.getX());

        }

    };


    SpriteParticleSystem spritePS = new SpriteParticleSystem(emitter, 1, 5, 50, starTR, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    spritePS.addParticleInitializer(new ScaleParticleInitializer<Sprite>(0.5f));
    spritePS.addParticleInitializer(new VelocityParticleInitializer<Sprite>(-10, 10, 100, 200));
    spritePS.addParticleInitializer(new AccelerationParticleInitializer<Sprite>(0f, 50f));
    spritePS.addParticleInitializer(new RotationParticleInitializer<Sprite>(0f, 360f));
    spritePS.addParticleInitializer(new ExpireParticleInitializer<Sprite>(1.0f, 15.0f));
    spritePS.addParticleModifier(new RotationParticleModifier<Sprite>(0.0f, 15.0f, 0, 360));


    scene.attachChild(spritePS);
```

star is a sprite I want to emit particles. When I drag it the particles do not move (except their own movement upwards)

Comment: Works great! Basically the ParticleSystem MUST be a child to the Scene otherwise all sprite emitted are bound to the parent and move along with it. To set the center of the emitter I used particleSystem.getParticleEmitter(), cast to BaseParticleEmitter and used setCenter.